# Can't Add AppWidget

Tags: android, launcher

I'm compiling ADW source code.
(https://github.com/AnderWeb/android_packages_apps_Launcher/archives/b28e9e417c81857cfd2e0265c3c6d409d6c8d0f1)

I wanna add widget more quickly,

so I add a menu item:

```
menu.add(MENU_GROUP_NORMAL, MENU_ADD_WIDGET, 0, R.string.menu_widget)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_compass);
```

and the relevant action when clicked:

```
case MENU_ADD_WIDGET:
    showAppWidgetList();
    return true;
```

the *showAppWidgetList()* does the same thing as when you click Menu->Add->Widget .

Then I click "my widget item" and the PickWidget dialog shows up,

after clicking a widget,

nothing happens!!!

No widget config or position setting dialog appears.

On the other hand,

if I click Menu->Add->Widget  and add a widget,

then Menu->"my widget item" and pick a widget,

then everything works just fine.

How strange!!!

Anybody know what's wrong with it??

Comment: The only people on the planet capable of answering this question are the ones who wrote the source code that you are modifying, and they are very unlikely to see this question. Please contact whoever "ADW" is and ask your question of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Menu->Add->Widget` does something before your `showAppWidgetList()`, you need to do the same thing before `showAppWidgetList()`.

Analyze the source code, you can find out that the Launcher does the following:

```
mAddItemCellInfo = mMenuAddInfo;
mWaitingForResult = true;
showAppWidgetList();
// your method
```